# How to round a number 3 significant figures in C++

Tags: c++, rounding, significant-digits

My goal is very simple I just want to round a number by 3 significant figures

for example if the user inputs:

`655900   433.72`

rounding it to 3 significant figures should look like :
`656000   434`

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: `std::round` is for rounding. Once you know how to round to integer you can also round `x * 100` and divide the result by `100`

Comment: Maybe [[c++] round digits](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+round+digits)

Comment: Is this just for output (like `cout` or `printf`) or do you need to store the rounded floating point number?

Comment: @Paul Floyd its for cout

Comment: Have you tried std::setprecision https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision ?